# Adding two columns and storing in third column in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have tried several suggestions from stackoverflow, but I keep running into errors.

What I have is a table: test

I have 3 columns:

```
first (varchar)
last (varchar)
first_last (varchar)
```

What I want to do, is build a trigger, so when I enter first and last, and save it, the value of first_last is computed and saved. Here's what I have now:

```
Trigger name: update_first_last
Table: test
Time: AFTER
Event: INSERT
Definition: UPDATE test SET test.first_last=CONCAT(test.first, test.last)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'test' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Comment: Dont do it. just concatenate `first` and `last` whenever you want to see a full name

Comment: Please give examples of what you have tried, and errors that you got.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to do it? I realize I can concatenate later, but what means running a script and I want the effect to be instant

Comment: This is a display concern, not a database concern. Storing duplicate data for no particular reason other than presentation is usually counter-productive.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper he is not suggesting `UPDATE`ing with a concat later; he is saying it is a bad idea to even be storing the concatenation. Generally speaking, your data consumers should never be looking directly at the table, and your applications should be smart enough to do the concatenation locally when they need to; so there is almost never a reason to store such redundant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the insert statement and your trigger want to modify the whole table which is not allowed. You can make something like this instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_first_last
BEFORE INSERT
ON test
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.first_last=CONCAT(NEW.first, NEW.last)
```

If the columns *first* and *last* are not defined as *NOT NULL* then you should create a similar trigger for an *UPDATE* action.

Comment: I get the following error message: #1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: That's right, I've changed the command - should be BEFORE INSERT.